# Bulk Fetching from a table in hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, bulk-load

I have a table and from that I am fetching records somewhere  around 250,000 records and this is taking some 25 mins, is there a way to decrease the fetch time. I am using some code like below :-

```
query.setParameterList("studentId", StudentIdList);
```

Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: Do you have a index on this column in your database? How long does it take if you do the same search from an SQL command line?

Comment: i think u need to create an index over studentId

Comment: @peter, i have an index on the student id and it takes less than 10 mins when i fetch it from SQL command line.

Comment: @Suraj : please see my comment above..

Comment: dont know much, but is this a prepared statement internally...in which case u might need to enable dynamic_prepare

Comment: @M.J. You need to determine if it is the cost of preparing the statement or the cost of building the objects. 10 min to read 250,000 records sounds like a long time, but it looks like its taking even longer in Java.

Comment: @Peter : 25 min is when i execute an HQL, which return me the object of the entity i have mapped to that table.

Comment: @M.J. so are you saying it takes 25 mins to get the first entry? 8-)

Comment: @Peter : No, i get all the entries but after 25 mins , which is hell lot of time.. i think..

Comment: @M.J. I agree, however the only advice I can give is to not use Hibernate, but I am sure some can suggest a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it takes less than 10 minutes from the SQL command line and more than 25 minutes from Hibernate then you may want to look into the information on [batching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).  In particular you might benefit from a stateless session (especially if you're not doing much work).  If you're really not doing much work you may be able to use a DML statement (also in that URL).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to optimize it?

If you want to make it faster you can do a bulk export and load from a file.  Or just not use the data base ;)

You can go much faster with other approaches to storing data.  You might get performance like this with a database, but sometimes the simplest approaches are best.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("students.csv");

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < 250 * 1000; i++)
        pw.println("student " + i + ", last " + i + ", email.address" + i + "@my-school.com," + i);
    pw.close();

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    for (String line; ((line = br.readLine()) != null);) {
        int pos = line.indexOf(',');
        int pos2 = line.indexOf(',', pos + 1);
        int pos3 = line.indexOf(',', pos2 + 1);
        students.add(new Student(line.substring(0, pos), line.substring(pos + 1, pos2), line.substring(pos2 + 1, pos3), Integer.parseInt(line.substring(pos3 + 1))));
    }
    br.close();
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Time to load %,d students was %.1f ms.%n", students.size(), time / 1e6);
}
```

I used Student from http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/32class/Student.java.html

prints

```
Time to load 250,000 students was 228.7 ms.
```

Comment: @Mogsdad as a user of SO you know that you cannot place long, formatted code into a comment. If you have a thoughtful suggest, I would be interested.

Comment: @Mogsdad it is framed as an answer, although I suspect the OP may have lost interest about four years ago.